# MIME type not allowed when importing with absolute path with Vite + React JS

Tags: reactjs, vite

When I setup Vite to load components using absolute path I get this MIME type not allowed console error.

vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
const path = require('path');

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: [{ find: '@', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, '/src') }]
  }
});
```

jsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"]
    }
  }
}
```

import:

```
import Container from '@/Components/UI/Container/Container';
```

[image: console error]

Any solution?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-path-alias-in-react-app?file=src/App.jsx). Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: As we can't see it, he should also share the implementation of the `<script></script>` tag in the `index.html`  file to be sure that he is not missing the `type` attribute from the script tag.

Comment: @tony19 I think the problem is with NodeJS because uploaded a test to GitHub and built it with Netlify and it worked. I'm getting the error only when I run dev on localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following configs worked for me. It is set for vueJs but also works well with react

In vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
```

import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import path from 'path'

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    },
  },
})
```

In jsconfig.json

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

[The configs are from here](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-set-up-path-resolving-in-vite-ad284e0d9eae)